# react-select component, not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-select

react: ^15.4.2,
react-select: ^1.0.0-rc.10,

**Example.tsx**

```
 import * as React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
// Be sure to include styles at some point, probably during your bootstrapping
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

var Select = require('react-select');
var options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

function logChange(val) {
  console.log("Selected: " + JSON.stringify(val));
}

export class Example extends React.Component<any, any> {

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <Select name="form-field-name" value="one" options={options} onChange={logChange}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

No errors reported at compile time.

Get an error message when attempting to render it

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. Check the render method of `Example`.
>       in Example

Being this is my first react project I have no idea how to debug this.  I do not see anything wrong with this code.

Here is my render out of main.tsx

```
    (() => {

    const container = document.querySelector('#container');
    render( <Example />, container);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the example above which is copy-pasted from `react-select` docs seems that everything is alright. The error says that you try to render something that is not being able to render (here it says it's some `Object`).
My bet is this line causes the error:

```
import Select from 'react-select';
```

are you sure you properly installed this package?

Answer (score 0):

Try to usw curly brackets arround Select in your import statement:

`import {Select} from...`

If there are no "default" export defined, you have to use those curly bracets to define the component you want to use.

Comment: I tried that, it is not that.  The research I have done is when I run. create-react-app then paste the code in it runs fine but I noticed the extensions for the files are in the project are .js  I am create an Office Web-AddIN which has an extension of tsx.  I was under the impression that they are inter changeable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Select from 'react-select';

class App extends Component {
    state = {options: [
        {
            value: '1', label: 'Option 1',
        },
        {
            value: '2', label: 'Option 2',
        }
    ]}

    render(){
          return (
            <div> 
                    <Select
                        className={"select-item"}
                        name="option name"
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        options={this.state.options}
                  />
              </div>
         )
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add an explanation of why this would fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
// Be sure to include styles at some point, probably during your bootstrapping
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';  


export class Example extends React.Component<any, any> {
  var options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
  ];

  function logChange(val) {
    console.log("Selected: " + JSON.stringify(val));
  }
  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <Select name="form-field-name" value="one" options={options} onChange={logChange}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, this should work:

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-vaughan-z4mkv?file=/src/Example.tsx

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
// Be sure to include styles at some point, probably during your bootstrapping
import "react-select/dist/react-select.css";

var options = [
  { value: "one", label: "One" },
  { value: "two", label: "Two" }
];

function logChange(val) {
  console.log("Selected: " + JSON.stringify(val));
}

export default class Example extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value="one"
          options={options}
          onChange={logChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Reason for error:

1. Either use `export default class Example extends React.Component<any, any> {`, or in whichever file you are importing and using `<Example />`, import it as `import { Example } from './path/to/file'`. Not using the `default` export specifier or named import in the importing file is causing the error. Read [imports / exports in js](https://javascript.info/import-export#export-default)

Things to do:

1. Remove `var Select = require('react-select');`. This is the same as `import Select from 'react-select';`, just in a different import format (read about ESM and CommonJS to learn more). We should avoid importing components
2. Use `import React from 'react'` instead.